# Meteor run a function when a mongo collection gets updated

Tags: meteor

I am trying to do a simple prototype using Meteor (I am very new to Meteor).

I have the following in an isClient block

```
    Template.imageList.helpers({
    images: function() {
        return Images.find({});
  },
}
);
```

Then for quick demo purposes I am inserting data with meteor mongo and the following

```
db.images.insert({ imgSrc: "http://mysite/img1.png", createdAt: new Date() })
```

This works and I can see the change reflected on the ui but I need to also run a client side javascript function when this occurs.  I have been trying things like pub/sub and Tracker but can't get anything to work.

Any guidance would be great.

Comment: Code within the 'images' helper is reactive by default, so it will change when the collection publication updates. You could run a script before you return, but this might trigger more than once per change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `observeChanges` :

```
Images.find().observeChanges({
   added: function (id, fields) {
       runFunction();
   },
   changed: function (id, fields) {
       runFunction();
   },
   removed: function (id) {
       runFunction();
  }
});
```

See here for more: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes

Comment: While I don't know if this is the best answer this is very close to what I did to solve the problem but I did wrap this in a Meteor.autosubscribe(...).

Answer (score 4):

Using [meteor-collections-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) its the more easy way to accomplish this.

```
meteor add matb33:collection-hooks
```

For example.

```
Images = new Mongo.Collection('Images')
example = function(){
  console.log("updated")
}
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Images.before.update(function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options){
     example();
  })
}
```

the `example()` function will run each time the `Images collection` get updated.

Comment: This is only effective if the collection get updated from Meteor side. If get updated from external service, this does not work

Comment: @ThaiTran can you expand on the above? I'm hitting an issue and trying to figure out if the fact the data is coming via a webhook is the issue. All of the data is still updated via a collection though.

Comment: @Rockafella as Meteor 1.3 you might dont need collections:hooks package, you can instead subclass your collection, check out this `class ListsCollection extends Mongo.Collection {
  // ...
  remove(selector, callback) {
    Package.todos.Todos.remove({listId: selector});
    return super.remove(selector, callback);
  }
}`

Comment: thanks @Ethaan, i'll look into that approach! This time I went with collection:hooks on the server and just `.observe` on the client (my original issue was collection:hooks on the client was not firing)

Comment: i think observer is very heavy to use on the client, you can instead approach for different solutions, but if it works for you, i guess is ok @Rockafella

Answer (score 0):

Run function on the client's template helper, like:

```
Template.imageList.helpers({
  images: function() {
    imgs = Images.find({});
    yourFunction();
    return images;
  }
});
```

Or use `Tracker.autorun` wrapper:

```
Tracker.autorun(
   Images.find({});
   yourFunction();
)
```