# Meteor client mongodb on change

Tags: meteor

A Meteor server causes a collection update which also updates the client copy of the collection.
Is there a way to invoke a client function whenever a record in client copy of the collection gets updated? Thanks

```
//server
Meteor.users.update({
      _id: Meteor.userId()
    }, {
      $set: {
        'profile.goAhead': true
      });

    //client
    if (Meteor.user().profile.goAhead) {
      myFunc();
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a (near) duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596256/meteor-run-a-function-when-a-mongo-collection-gets-updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [.observeChanges()](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges)

```
let query = MyCollections.find();
query.observeChanges({
  added(id,fields){
    console.log("Document added with _id "+id);
  },
  changed(id,fields){
    console.log("Document with _id "+id+" was changed");
  },
  // ... there are more possible callbacks
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Meteor has optimistic update. The client copy is first updated. Then at a convenient time, the server collection is updated. If there are any issues with the server update, then the client copy is rolled back or updated with different value.

In the above code, the server update should be wrapped in Meteor.methods(). Calling a server method from the client has a callback method which can be used in this case.

Comment: here is an article of how optimistic update works: https://hashnode.com/post/optimistic-updates-in-meteor-cip7wr11m082zya53uft4xtb5